# How can I compare if the author is in the same voice channel as the bot?

Tags: python, discord, bots

The title describes everything.
And be simple as possible please because I began yesterday with coding my bot. Thx
Code:

```
@bot.command(name='leave', help='leave from a voice channel')
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice == ctx.voice_client.channel: # <-- this doesn't work
        if (ctx.voice_client):
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
            await ctx.send(f'I left from {channel}')
        else:
            await ctx.send("I'm not to a voice channel to leave.")
    else:
        await ctx.send('You are not allowed to do that')
```

Comment: In line 3 there is for the channel of the author:
ctx.author.voice.channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your other code, the check should be as below?

```
if ctx.author.voice.channel == ctx.voice_client.channel
```

Comment: works! Thank you. Do you also know, how to send a message to a specific member?